# jQuery: Set listener to group of links

Tags: jquery, html, database, dom

Ok I need to know the best way to handle this situation.

I have a number of buttons on the screen using code similar to the following.

```
<a id="btn[1]" class="button">Some Text</a>
<a id="btn[2]" class="button">Some Text</a>
<a id="btn[etc]" class="button">Some Text</a>
```

The number inside the [] inside the id tag refers to record id that I need to strip out later for ajax purposes.

To set up a listener to this set of buttons I would normally using something like this:

```
$('.button').live('click', function() {
     do something with items blah blah blah
}
```

However I am using other buttons on the page that also use the button class that I do not want this listener attached to. So I was hoping there was an easy way to work around this. like grabbing the set of elements by tag name or something in the ref attribute???

Any ideas with syntax would be appreciated.

Comment: `$('a.button')` ??? Or worst: `$('a[id^=btn]')`? The best way would certainly be to use a distinct class instead

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: @wolff won't $('a.button') grab all the button class links on the page; not just the one? These are in a table should I use something like $(table tr.button)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @j08691 said, the `.live()` function ins deprecated.
Further you need to set the handler to the parent element and provide an "second" selector (defining the target-childs) parameter to make `.on()` work delegated.

---

from http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one eleme
nt, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody):